# How do I bind to a property?

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding

Here's my simplified scenario.  I can adjust my inner rectangle width using the mouse.  A textblock displays the width which changes as I adjust it.  I want a second textblock to display the value of a property which also changes with the width but I cannot figure out how to bind it.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Center">

    <Rectangle x:Name="aRec" Height="100" Width="100" MinWidth="10" Fill="Blue" />

    <Rectangle x:Name="myRec" Height="100" Width="300" MinWidth="10" Fill="Red" Opacity="0.5" 
               MouseLeftButtonDown="myRec_MouseLeftButtonDown" 
               MouseLeftButtonUp="myRec_MouseLeftButtonUp" 
               MouseMove="myRec_MouseMove"></Rectangle>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="myText1" Width="40" Height="20" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding ElementName=aRec, Path=Width}" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="myText2" Width="40" Height="20" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Value}" />
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>

public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    Boolean active = false;

    private Double _value;
    public Double Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void myRec_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        active = true;
    }

    private void myRec_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (active == true)
        {
            aRec.Width = e.GetPosition(myRec).X;
            _value = aRec.Width * 10;
        }
    }

    private void myRec_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        active = false;
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **MainPage** must implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) interface (example for [How to: Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx)) and your properties must fire event on set, or you must use [Dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221408%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for **Value**.
Also on **myRec_MouseMove** hanlder assign width to *Value* property, not *_value* member.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the property "Value" as a dependency property.

Answer (score 0):

In your code-behind:

```
myText2.DataContext = Value;
```

In your xaml:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myText2" Width="40" Height="20" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Path=.}" />
```

"Path=." will point to your datacontext.